# How to open a link in a pop up iframe window

Tags: html, iframe

I have text that I need to link to where you click on it and an iframe window pops up with the content from an external site. I have found code that when I use it, a box appears above the text and the content shows in the box when clicked. But I need it to not show anything until the link is clicked.

```
<iframe name="book" src="https://www.timetrade.com/book/9PK2K"></iframe>
<a href='https://www.timetrade.com/book/9PK2K' target="book">Book Now!</a>
```

This is the code I used to try to get it to link to a pop up iframe window but it showed a box above the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some javascript for this.

A simple onClick() method that sets the display to 'Block' and 'None' to display and hide, respectively, should do the trick.

The javascript would set style.display="none" by default, and the onClick will be written to set style.display="block" or some un-hidden attribute.

Check out this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp for onClick 
and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp for using javascript to show/hide DOM objects.

Good luck!

Comment: Javascript is very foreign to me. How would I insert an iframe to that?

Comment: If you're doing web stuff like this I highly recommend you get yourself familiar with the basics of javascript, its super useful. You can use the onclick with the <a></a> in the same way you use it for the button on that page I sent. It's just another attribute added to the DOM element.

Comment: Check out w3schools javascript tutorial for an introduction to how it works

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into it! Trying to find how to incorporate an iframe link.

Comment: I think it would behave the same way as if it weren't an iframe, but yea good luck!